# ImportError: cannot import name 'opentype' on new installation

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I've just created a Google Cloud compute engine, installed google-cloud package with both pip and pip3, and I'm experiencing the following error when launching a script with python3

```
    from google.cloud import bigquery
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 35, 
in <module>
    from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 36, in
 <module>

(more traceback lines..)

    from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import Certificate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py", line 20, in <modu
le>
    from pyasn1.type import opentype
ImportError: cannot import name 'opentype'
```

On the compute engine the following packages are installed:

```
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
google-cloud==0.30.0
google-cloud-bigquery==0.28.0
```

Which can be the problem here?

Comment: You may try upgrading pyasn1 to the latest https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyasn1, because in my machine I have the latest and there were no issues while importing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you have an issue with *pyasn1*, so you could try installing a newer version (the latest is **0.4.2**), or even reinstalling it manually with:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules
```

---

And if you are inside a *virtualenv*, use instead:

```
pip install pyasn1 pyasn1-modules
```

Comment: I have a similar problem on the raspberrypi 3, but this solution didn't seem to work. I have posted a question here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=114&t=198933&p=1241255#p1241255

Comment: Use the same command without the *sudo*, because for what I've seen, you are running the code inside a virtualenv, and then you will have to install the libraries inside the virtualenv, not in the external system.

Comment: My bad. I double checked, and in order to install inside a virtualenv, *apt-get* does not work. Try using this command instead, whe you are inside your virtualenv:

`pip install pyasn1 pyasn1-modules`

Comment: @Yandrak3 Thanks for that - I found in the end that what I needed was `pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib`.

Answer (score 43):

Posting my solution in case it helps someone else - this fixed it for me:

`pip install --upgrade google-auth-oauthlib`

More details discussed here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=114&t=198933&p=1241439#p1241439

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - Had the same issue - none of the above worked. I eventually discovered that if I did it under `sudo` it *did* work.

stracing the original - I found that I had a `~/.local` directory which had a pyasn1 directory where it was trying to get the files from, but the *opentype.py* one did *not* appear there. When I deleted that whole directory - it started working.

I assume it was some sort of cache that was partial, and out-of-date???