# Issue with the import of opentype when python script is started from rc.local

Tags: python, raspbian, python-module, opentype

What I am trying to do is to execute a python script on a Raspbian startup. The way I do it is by putting this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/MyProj/sample/main.py > /home/pi/Desktop/projStartup.log 2>&1 &
exit 0
```

The way it is written basically means that I am starting it as a forked process (**'&'** at the end) and each log should go into the **projStartup.log** file.

When I open the terminal and type:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /etc/rc.local
```

everything works as expected but when I try to restart my Raspbian I get the following error (top of the error stack):

```
File "/home/pi/Desktop/MyProj/sample/firebaseManager.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyrebase import pyrebase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrebase import initialize_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py", line 17, in <module>
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 26, in <module>
    from oauth2client import crypt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 23, in <module>
    from oauth2client import _pure_python_crypt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_pure_python_crypt.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import Certificate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyasn1.type import opentype
ImportError: cannot import name opentype
```

As you can see, there's an issue with the import of **opentype**. I had similar issues with other modules that are being used by my script and the solution was to install them globally by using:

```
sudo pip install ...
```

So, now I am wondering what needs to be updated on a global level in order to be able to avoid this opentype issue.

Comment: In general, every external module that your program depends on. In a few cases you can get lucky with `cd /home/pi/Desktop/MyProj/sample && /sr/bin/python main.py > ../projStartup.log 2>&1 &` but in general you need to write a `setup.py` file and install your package globally.

Comment: It didn't work in my case. I still get the same error. Do you think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47600597/import-error-cannot-import-name-opentype

Comment: Not if you can run your command from the shell.  Does it work if you `cd /etc` and then `sudo rc.local`? (that's the working dir and user that normally runs rc.local)

Comment: I can not start rc.local like this. I get sudo: rc.local: command not found

But if I do: /etc/rc.local from the root it works. If I put 'sudo' in front (sudo /etc/rc.local) I get this very same opentype error.

Comment: sudo -H -u pi /etc/rc.local works.

Comment: ok, then it is because the root user doesn't have access to the modules that you've installed as the `pi` user. Maybe (in rc.local) `su pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/MyProj/sample/main.py .. ` will get you there..?

Comment: Yes, it got me there and now script is being executed on startup! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as suggested by @thebjorn

**SOLUTION**: The solution for me was to explicitly set the pi user (the one that I use when logged in).

```
sudo -H -u pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/MyProj/sample/main.py > /home/pi/Desktop/projStartup.log 2>&1 &
```